# Amazon echo show not responding to new smart home skill

Tags: alexa-skills-kit, alexa-voice-service, amazon-echo

I have created a smart home skill for testing my amazon echo show integration with my smart camera. I have created a lambda function. When I test it on the AWS Lambda console it works fine. Below is the request body that I am using to test

```
{
  "header": {
    "namespace": "Alexa.ConnectedHome.Query",
    "name": "RetrieveCameraStreamUriRequest",
    "payloadVersion": "2",
    "messageId": "ABC-123-DEF-456"
  },
  "payload": {
    "accessToken": "[OAuth Token here]",
    "directedId": "[directed customer id]",
    "appliance": {
      "applianceId": "[Device ID for the camera]",
      "additionalApplianceDetails": {
        "extraDetail1": "optionalDetailForSkillAdapterToReferenceThisDevice",
        "extraDetail2": "There can be multiple entries",
        "extraDetail3": "but they should only be used for reference purposes.",
        "extraDetail4": "Not a suitable place to maintain current device state"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The response I get is

```
{
  "header": {
    "messageId": "38A28869-DD5E-48CE-BBE5-A4DB78CECB28",
    "name": "RetrieveCameraStreamUriResponse",
    "namespace": "Alexa.ConnectedHome.Query",
    "payloadVersion": "2"
  },
  "payload": {
    "uri": {
      "value": "rtsp://xyz.com/playback/9a78b68f68ae4538a1cf"
    },
    "imageUri": {
      "value": "https://www.google.co.in/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png"
    }
  }
}
```

But when I test this with my alexa echo show it says "camera is not responding"

Can anyone suggest anything here?

Comment: Your response's messageId is different from the request's?

Answer (score 0):

I needed to specify 443 port in the URL... The issue is with

```
"value":"rtsp://xyz.com/playback/9a78b68f68ae4538a1cf".
```

The doc says it only works with Interleaved TCP on port 443 (for both RTP and RTSP).

This now works

```
{
  "header": {
    "messageId": "38A28869-DD5E-48CE-BBE5-A4DB78CECB28",
    "name": "RetrieveCameraStreamUriResponse",
    "namespace": "Alexa.ConnectedHome.Query",
    "payloadVersion": "2"
  },
  "payload": {
    "uri": {
      "value": "rtsp://xyz.com:443/playback/9a78b68f68ae4538a1cf"
    },
    "imageUri": {
      "value": "https://www.google.co.in/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png"
    }
}
```